# Why "verschwende" and not "verschwendest" in this song?

Tags: word-choice, verb, verb-choice, verb-usage

I found a Youtube video located [here](http://youtu.be/3B-EMmsawJc?t=2m31s)
It contains the following lyric "Verschwende deine Zeit nicht an mir, denn Du bist bereits die Stimme in meinem Kopf"

I thought since he addressed them with "Du" in the sentence you would conjugate the verb in that way.

Also, keep in mind I feel that I'm an idiot sometimes and if your response is really short and simple I may not get it. So feel free to give an example.

**Bonus Question**: Could you say "dem Kopf" in that sentence without changing the meaning?

Comment: Your link does not work in Germany, for copyright reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Verschwende" is the imperative form of "verschwenden".

The speaker says she *should* not waste her time with him, not that she actually does it (although this is implied).

An no, you cannot replace "meinem" mit "dem" in this context. It would not really change the meaning, but it would simply be wrong or at least extremely unidiomatic.

Comment: Oh, so it looks like I need to study the Imperative Form next. Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

"Verschwende deine Zeit nicht an mir," translates into "Don't (you) waste your time on me."

That is a "command" or imperative form, used with Du. (Actually, it's in the negative.)

The conjugated form would be: "Du verschwendest deine Zeit nicht an mir." This would mean, "You do not waste your time on me," which is a "declarative" sentence.